# find key in dictionary and print value

Tags: python, dictionary

Hello everyone I am stuck on a class assignment and not sure where to go at this point as my college does not offer tutors for the programming field as this is the first semester that this has been offered. Assignment is:

Write a program that:

3. Prints out the toy name for that code in a useful message such as, ‘The toy for that code is a Baseball’
4. The program exits when instead of a toy code, the user enters ‘quit’

below is a sample of the text file that the dict is suppose to populate from

D1,Tyrannasaurous

D2,Apatasauros

D3,Velociraptor

D4,Tricerotops

D5,Pterodactyl

T1,Diesel-Electric

T2,Steam Engine

T3,Box Car

and what I have gotten so far is:

**

```
fin=open('C:/Python34/Lib/toys.txt','r')
print(fin)
toylookup=dict()     #creates a dictionary named toy lookup
def get_line():             #get a single line from the file
    newline=fin.readline()  #get the line
    newline=newline.strip() #strip away extra characters
    return newline
print ('please enter toy code here>>>')
search_toy_code= input()
for toy_code in toylookup.keys():
    if toy_code == search_toy_code:
        print('The toy for that code is a','value')
    else:
        print("toy code not found")
```

**

and to be honest I am not even sure I am right with what I have. any help at all would be greatly appreciate thank you.

Comment: I highly recommend stripping the question down to a specific problem you're having. Posting the entire assignment is a bit daunting for people to read through and answer! :) Perhaps try summarizing it a little?

Comment: Supply a sample snippet of "toys.txt" and the desired output of your script. Also try to narrow down the question. Evaluating your code is hard if one does not know how "toys.txt" looks like ;)

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I cant get anything to print out for a return value

Comment: Isn't your `toylookup` empty dict? I don't see populating it anywhere...

Comment: it populating the dict from the file or at least it is suppose to be

Comment: Your code does not populate the dict. Look at my answer, working example.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

1. Your dictionary isn't getting populated; however there currently isn't enough info in your question to help with that problem. Need to know what the file looks like, etc.
2. Your lookup loop won't display the values for keys that match. Below is the solution for that.

Try iterating over `key`:`value` pairs like this:

```
for code, toy in toylookup.items():
    if key == search_toy_code:
        print('The toy for that code ({}) is a {}'.format(code, toy))
    else:
        print("Toy code ({}) not found".format(code))
```

Take a look at the docs for [dict.items()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

> **items()**:
>
> Return a new view of the dictionary’s items ((key, value) pairs).

Comment: If you populate the dictionary mapping from code to toy name, you don't need to iterate any more. Just check `if code in toylookup` and if the key is there, use `toylookup[code]`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make yourself familiar with basic python programming. In order to solve such tasks you need to know about basic data structures and loops.

```
# define path and name of file
filepath = "test.txt"  # content like: B1,Baseball B2,Basketball B3,Football

# read file data
with open(filepath) as f:
    fdata = f.readlines()  # reads every line in fdata
                           # fdata is now a list containing each line

# prompt the user
print("please enter toy code here: ")
user_toy_code = input()

# dict container
toys_dict = {}

# get the items with toy codes and names
for line in fdata:  # iterate over every line
    line = line.strip()  # remove extra whitespaces and stuff
    line = line.split(" ")  # splits "B1,Baseball B2,Basketball"
                            # to ["B1,Baseball", "B2,Basketball"]
    for item in line:  # iterate over the items of a line
        item = item.split(",")  # splits "B1,Baseball"
                                # to ["B1", "Baseball"]
        toys_dict[item[0]] = item[1]  # saves {"B1": "Baseball"} to the dict

# check if the user toy code is in our dict
if user_toy_code in toys_dict:
    print("The toy for toy code {} is: {}".format(user_toy_code, toys_dict[user_toy_code]))
else:
    print("Toy code {} not found".format(user_toy_code))
```